# Measuring current drawn on a 12V rail

Tags: current-measurement

I'm looking for a high side current monitor which can measure 0-3A on a 12V rail with either a built in sense resistor or with a hall effect current sensor. I'm also space constrained, to SOT-23 or so in size. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use an Allegro linear hall sensor, and lay out a current loop under the SOT-23 package? I haven't done the math. Use Ampère's Law and the sensor datasheet to see how likely this is to work.

Comment: I've found a SOIC-8 sensor for 0-5A, which would be good enough, but it would be better if I could go even smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Allegro is often a first choice for high side current monitors, but it appears they don't have anything smaller than SOIC, like the [ACS712](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/0712/0712.pdf), CMIIW. This has the current sensor itself integrated, so it may compete with a SOT-23 solution.

For a SOT-23 you have for instance the Zetex [ZXCT1009](http://www.diodes.com/zetex/_pdfs/3.0/pdf/ZXCT1009.pdf). This has a transconductance of 10mA/V; a short PCB trace could serve as current sensor. A 1cm zigzag trace 0.2mm wide then gives you 250\$\mu\$A/A, so a 1k\$\Omega\$ load resistor will result in 750mV full scale.